# Update queries in all Excel files

Tags: excel, powerquery

There are 5 Excel files that I periodically need to open and refresh the queries in each (these link to databases, csv files etc). Is there a way to refresh all queries in these 5 files in one go? I know you have a "refresh all" button in Excel but this applies to the active file only, not the rest of the Excel files that are open.

Comment: You can... use a macro to (open and) refresh the files. There are ways to do this outside of Excel with something like a scheduled Powershell script. There's no magical way to have an Excel file update the data in it without it being refreshed by either a person or some code though.

Comment: Do you have such a macro to open and refresh the files before closing them?